# In Eclipse, exclude some files from debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Is it possible to exclude files from debugging in Eclipse?

There are my files which I have written and I am interesting in going through these files using debugger Step Over command.

But there are also many imported library files and Step Over goes into these files, which I'd like to avoid. So is there an option eother to specify which files to debug or which files to exclude?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a JVM based language (as you didn't specify), under Preferences, filter for Step Filtering.

You will see a list of packages. Add your packages to the list, and ensure Use Step Filters is selected.

Assuming it's an entire package you want filtered out, and you're using Java, this should do what you want.